# Math Random sin repetir letras

Tags: java, netbeans, matrices, caracteres

Tengo un codigo que genera letras al azar pero necesito que no repita la misma letra mas de dos veces al imprimir, al igual que me gustaria saber como imprimirlo como si fuera una matriz de 2 columnas.

```
char []chr={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
        char[][] aleatorio = new char[26][2];
 
        for(int i=0; i<=25; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<=1; j++)
            aleatorio[i][j]=chr[(int)(Math.random()*26)];

        }
            for(int i=0; i<=25; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<=1; j++)
            System.out.println(aleatorio[i][j]);

        }
```

Comment: con el metodo `shuffle` esto hara que tu arreglo se ordene de forma aleatoria...  luego ya seria recorrerlo e impirmirlo...

Comment: Como lo aplico en ese char? proque si sirve puedo quitar el MathRandom

Comment: Dices más de dos veces. Entonces se puede repetir una letra al menos 1 vez? De hecho, *no más de dos veces* implica que se pueden repetir 0, 1 y hasta 2 veces máximo.